# Angular 7 not able to play vimeo video on safari 12

Tags: angular, express, angular-cli

I am using Angular 7 and expressjs to host an application. My application is getting Vimeo video Id from third party APIs and then I am trying to show videos on my page with the help of Vimeo API to get the video link using vimeo video Id. Everything is working fine on chrome but when it comes to Safari 12 my videos are not rendering. The error is

> "The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored.".

Here is the screenshot of error which we are facing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WZjD.png

Any suggestion is welcome.

I tried setting the CSP on the express server using the **helmet-csp** module but no luck.

```
this.selectedJobDetails.JobVideo = this.selectedJobDetails.JobVideo.map((elem) => {
    if (elem.url && elem.venderId == 2) {
            this.vimeoService.getVideoDataById(elem.url).subscribe(response => {
                if (response && response.files && response.files instanceof Array && response.files.length > 0) {
elem.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(response.files[0]['link']);
  }
   });
} else if (elem.url && elem.venderId == 1) {
  elem.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(elem.url);
}
return elem;
});
```

```
<div class="video-col" *ngFor="let video of selectedJobDetails?.JobVideo">
   <div class="vid-clip" *ngIf="video.url">
        <video [src]="video.url" controls type=""></video>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am getting the video urls from the vimeo video API and then sanitizing the url and then I am binding the src with video tag.

Any suggestion is welcome.